# How to write a practical https client in golang

Tags: go, https, client

I am building a https client in golang, which is supposed to connect to a specified host and get the server name from the header or the certificate of the host. This is my code

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    caCert, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("./cacert.pem")
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    conf := &tls.Config{RootCAs: caCertPool}
    conf.BuildNameToCertificate()
    tr := &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig: conf}
    cli := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    resp, _ := cli.Head("https://www.google.com")
    fmt.Println(resp.TLS.ServerName)
}
```

But it is running into a panic

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x88 pc=0x401314]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x7145e0, 0xc82000a100)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
main.main()
/home/huangjian/anti-GFW/go-checkgoogleip/checkip.go:22 +0x314
exit status 2
```

Maybe I am lack of solid knowledge of public key encryption but now I just want to make it work. Could anyone tell me where did I do wrongly and how to correct it?

Comment: If you do `resp, err := cli.Head("https://www.google.com")` and print `err`, what does it say?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it outputs **2016/04/13 16:34:15 Head https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=HAQOV9vnBcLU8AfktoiYCA: dial tcp 59.24.3.173:443: getsockopt: connection refused
exit status 1**

Comment: btw, you can nest struct pointer literals, ie ```cli := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{TLSClientConfig:conf}}```

Comment: what about printing the other err? ```caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./cacert.pem")```

Comment: @matt.s no error loading cacert.pem

Comment: When I specify the remote host as IP address `resp, err := cli.Head("https://202.86.162.172")` , I get this error **2016/04/13 17:51:18 Head https://202.86.162.172: x509: cannot validate certificate for 202.86.162.172 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
exit status 1** ,I don't understand what this is

Comment: The server doesn't know what certificate to use if you if you don't connect with a name, and you can't verify a cert without a name. A server might have a cert with a SAN for the IP address, but it's not likely. You should know how SNI works.